# Tensorflow memory problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nvidia-jetson

I am doing a project with object detection. I use a provided algorithm by Livox (https://github.com/Livox-SDK/livox_detection). I am doing the project on a Nvidia jetson xavier nx with 8 GB memory. I am using Tensorflow 1.15.4 because of compability reasons. The algorithm worked fine on TF 1.13.1 on a GTX 1050 graphics card but it was too slow.

When I start the algorithm, tensorflow allocates memory (for example 3000 mb). But when the algorithm is getting sensor data from the lidar sensor, the memory increases until it is nearly at the available 7700 Mb. After one minute all tracebacks were listed and the program starts but has a inference time at about 300 ms (50ms on the GTX 1050 and it should be 24 ms). I think that there is a problem with rewriting the used memory. The program works with a pre trained model, which means I can't train the model new because I don't have the dataset.

I will publish the main tracebacks below.

```
xavier@xavier-desktop:~/livox_detection-master$ python3 livox_rosdetection.py 
2021-03-29 18:43:51.996530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Deprecation warnings have been disabled. Set TF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1 to re-enable them.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

1008 224 30
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xavier/livox_detection-master/networks/model.py:27: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

(1, 1008, 224, 30)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xavier/livox_detection-master/networks/model.py:77: The name tf.image.resize_bilinear is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.image.resize_bilinear instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From livox_rosdetection.py:66: The name tf.train.Saver is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Saver instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From livox_rosdetection.py:67: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From livox_rosdetection.py:72: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2021-03-29 18:44:07.473530: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:98] Failed to find bogomips in /proc/cpuinfo; cannot determine CPU frequency
2021-03-29 18:44:07.474464: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x34229010 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-29 18:44:07.474578: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-03-29 18:44:07.524156: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-03-29 18:44:07.760361: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:07.760946: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x341f0ea0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-29 18:44:07.761005: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Xavier, Compute Capability 7.2
2021-03-29 18:44:07.761407: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:07.761515: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1665] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Xavier major: 7 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.109
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0
2021-03-29 18:44:07.761579: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-03-29 18:44:07.835484: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-03-29 18:44:07.854590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-03-29 18:44:07.894728: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-03-29 18:44:07.913741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-03-29 18:44:07.932242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-03-29 18:44:07.938152: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-29 18:44:07.938577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:07.939043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:07.939263: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1793] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-29 18:44:07.943363: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-03-29 18:44:14.396299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1206] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-29 18:44:14.396420: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212]      0 
2021-03-29 18:44:14.396449: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1225] 0:   N 
2021-03-29 18:44:14.396959: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:14.397271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1049] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-29 18:44:14.397482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1351] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3882 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Xavier, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 7.2)

2021-03-29 18:47:25.321906: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-29 18:47:42.396094: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-03-29 18:48:05.615685: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:419] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.89GiB (rounded to 4179165184).  Current allocation summary follows.
2021-03-29 18:48:05.637466: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 21, Chunks in use: 21. 5.2KiB allocated for chunks. 5.2KiB in use in bin. 4.6KiB client-requested in use in bin.

then some allocator lines like above

2021-03-29 18:48:05.699020: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:921] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 291.68MiB
2021-03-29 18:48:05.699180: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:923] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 4071376896 memory_limit_: 4071376896 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 8142753792
2021-03-29 18:48:05.699424: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:929] Stats: 
Limit:                  4071376896
InUse:                   305850368
MaxInUse:               3307795968
NumAllocs:                     198
MaxAllocSize:           3073374208

2021-03-29 18:48:05.715474: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:424] ********____________________________________________________________________________________________
2021-03-29 18:48:15.799330: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:419] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.89GiB (rounded to 4179165184).  Current allocation summary follows.
```

After that sometimes there is this traceback:

```
2021-03-28 14:37:45.895238: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:305] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
```

I already tried to limit the allocation amount with this line in the "livox_rosdetection.py" from the github link I mentioned before:

```
               # config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
                config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
```

One final thing to mention is that the memory gets split up between CPU and GPU.
When more information is required I will publish it.

Does someone know how I can make the detection faster?

thanks in advance